# First-open attribution in Firebase through Dynamic Links

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-dynamic-links

I am using Firebase on my ionic app for Analytics and it is working well (on iOS and Android).

I tried recently to setup a Dynamic Link with custom campaign, medium and source parameters for a marketing campaign. The clicks are well-tracked, I can see them in the Dynamic Links dashboard but I want to track the install and the first-open column stays at 0, it does not seem to work.

Same if I go to the "Attribution" dashboard, none of the first-open is attributed to my custom campaign.

Given that Firebase Analytics work well, do I need to configure anything more to track the installs from Dynamic Links ? I thought first-open was dealt with automatically.

Thanks

Comment: Have you found anything out about this?

Comment: No, I ended up using another service to track acquisition campaigns..

Answer (score 2):

I know it's late. I also thought it will be tracked automatically (that's what they say in the videos, right?) but it's not THAT smart. In my case, I just didn't configure both Android and iOS properly to *receive* these links. It turnes out (at least on Android) that you need to 'retrieve' the links in your app to make it work.

From Firebase documentation:

The following events can be automatically tracked in Google Analytics for Firebase and shown in the Firebase console.

- `dynamic_link_app_open`
- `dynamic_link_first_open`
- `dynamic_link_app_update`

In order to register these events, you need to configure Google Analytics for Firebase before you retrieve the deep link. Check the following conditions are met:

- Call `FirebaseDynamicLinks.getDynamicLink()` in your app entry points:

  - Launcher activities. e.g.: `action="android.intent.action.MAIN"`, `category="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"`.
  - Activity entry points. e.g.: `onStart()`, `onCreate()`.
  - Deep link activities.
- Set up and use Google Analytics for Firebase:
  Include the Google Analytics for Firebase dependency. This is usually automatically added by the `google-services` Gradle plugin.

  - Include the `google-services.json` config file in your app.
  - Call `FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance()` before calling
  - `FirebaseDynamicLinks.getDynamicLink()`.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/receive#record-analytics

I'm using `react-native-firebase` so I had to call `firebase.links().getInitialLink()` in my case (+ properly configure incoming links).

I hope this helps someone.